# Linear Algebra A level P-Norm Homogeneity

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Is this true for $p >1, a_i \epsilon R$: $$(\sum_{i=1}^n |ra_i|^p)^\frac{1}{p} = |r|(\sum|a_i|^p)^\frac{1}{p}$$

It seems to work for $p = 1$: $$(\sum_{i=1}^n |ra_i|^1)^\frac{1}{1} = \sum_{i=1}^n |r||a_i| = |r|\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i| = |r|(\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|^1)^\frac{1}{1} $$

For $p+1$ it gets a little tricky:

$$(\sum_{i=1}^n |ra_i|^{p+1})^\frac{1}{p+1} = $$ $$. . .$$ $$ |r|(\sum|a_i|^{p + 1})^\frac{1}{p + 1} $$

Any next step ideas to show it is also true for $p+1$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be a given real number such that $p \geq 1$.

Then for any real numbers $r, a_1, \ldots, a_n$, we obtain
$$
\begin{align}
\left( \sum_{i=1}^n \left\lvert r a_i \right\rvert^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} &= \left( \sum_{i=1}^n  \left( \left\lvert r a_i \right\rvert \right)^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \\
&= \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \lvert r \rvert \times  \left\lvert  a_i \right\rvert \right)^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \\
&= \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \lvert r \rvert^p \times \left\lvert  a_i \right\rvert^p \right) \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \\
&= \left( \lvert r \rvert^p \times  \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \left\lvert  a_i \right\rvert^p \right) \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \\
&= \left( \lvert r \rvert^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \times \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \left\lvert  a_i \right\rvert^p \right) \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \\
&= \lvert r \rvert  \left( \sum_{i=1}^n  \left\lvert  a_i \right\rvert^p  \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \\
\end{align}
$$